# FreeBSD pkg database deleted

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, corruption, fsck

after resolving repeated crashes on startup with `fsck` I noticed some files were removed, one of them was the sqlite pkg database, so now when I run for example `pkg install somepackage` I get this erro:

```
pkg: sqlite: file is encrypted or not a databse
```

So my question is actually two-fold:

1. How do I get `pkg` running again
2. Is there a way (logs?) to find out what file were removed with the `fsck` tool?

Comment: I am not aware of any log file for fsck execution.

Comment: When I think about it I realize that doing just `fsck -y > fsck.log` would've been enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (sqlite) database used by pkg(ng) is corrupted.

You should be able to restore the pkg db file using its daily backup:

- have a look at `/var/backups/`

  ```
  # ls -lrt /var/backups/pkg*
  -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  16462211 May  3 03:01 pkgdb.bak.tbz
  -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  16462853 Apr 16 03:01 pkgdb.bak.tbz.2
  -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  17824768 May  3 03:02 pkgng.db
  ```
- move away your corrupted db file (you can remove it later):

  ```
  # mv /var/db/pkg/local.sqlite /var/db/pkg/local.sqlite.corrupted
  ```
- use the latest backup to restore your pkg db file:

  ```
  # pkg backup -r /var/backups/pkgng.db
  ```

Comment: thanks, that worked, btw it was in `/var/backups/` :)

Comment: my bad: big fingers or bad sight ...